# apache-camel throttle does not work as expected

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic, throttling

Apache-Camel: 2.12.2, activemq: 5.7

We noticed that in the following route throttling works fine for the first 100 exchanges. After that instead of sending 100 exchanges per second, it sends only 1 exchange per second. Now if we set timePeriodMillis=100 it seems to be working fine. Note that we send 500 exchanges at the same time.

```
<bean id="myProject" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="myProjectPooledConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="preserveMessageQos" value="true" />
    <property name="transacted" value="false" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="10" />
</bean>

<bean id="myProjectPooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" destroy-method="stop" init-method="start">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="myProjectAmqConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="maxConnections" value="20" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean id="myProjectAmqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" >
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${myProject.broker.url}" />
    <property name="copyMessageOnSend" value="false" />
    <property name="useAsyncSend" value="true" />
</bean>


<!-- Local ActiveMQ Configuration -->
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="transacted" value="false"/>
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="500"/>
</bean>

<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" destroy-method="stop" init-method="start">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="amqConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="maxConnections" value="1" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean id="amqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" >
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${broker.url}" />
    <property name="copyMessageOnSend" value="false" />
    <property name="useAsyncSend" value="true" />
</bean>

<route id="myProject.outbound.traffic" errorHandlerRef="error.handler.myProject">
    <from uri="{{queue.myProject.mint.in}}{{queue.myProject.mint.in.args}}"/>
    <throttle timePeriodMillis="1000" >
            <constant>100</constant>
            <process ref="myProjectProcessor" />
            <inOnly uri="myProject:{{queue.myProject}}">
        <log logName="myProject.myProjectProcessor" loggingLevel="INFO" message="this is a test message" />
    </throttle>
</route>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine found the answer. It is a bug in camel 2.12.2 and it seems to have been solved in 2.12.3. It has to do with the way an exchange is assigned to a slot. Instead of checking if a slot is active it should check if the slot has past first.

```
protected synchronized TimeSlot nextSlot() {
    if (slot == null) {
        slot = new TimeSlot();
    }
    if (slot.isFull() || !slot.isActive()) {
        slot = slot.next();
    }
    slot.assign();
    return slot;
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/processor/Throttler.java)